# how to send emails of generated HTML reports in cypress

Tags: cypress

- - 36

    **tasksendMail, This will be output to email address**
- AFTER ALL (FAILED)

  - 1

    **tasksendMail, This will be output to email address**

CypressError

cy.task('sendMail') failed with the following error:

The task 'sendMail' was not handled in the setupNodeEvents method. The following tasks are registered: log

Fix this in your setupNodeEvents method here:
C:\xampp\htdocs\automation-testing\Cypress_Automation\cypress.config.js

Because this error occurred during a `after all` hook we are skipping all of the remaining tests.[Learn more](https://on.cypress.io/api/task)

cypress/support/e2e.js:31:8

```
  29 | 
  30 |  after(() => {
> 31 |     cy.task('sendMail', 'This will be output to email address')
     |        ^
  32 |       .then(result => console.log(result));
  33 |   })


I got this error when runs script
```

```
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  // setupNodeEvents can be defined in either
  // the e2e or component configuration
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        log(message) {
          console.log(message)

          return null
        },
      })
    },
  },
})

this is my cypress.config.js file


after(() => {
    cy.task('sendMail', 'This will be output to email address')
      .then(result => console.log(result));
  })

this is my e2e.js file


const sendAnEmail = (message) => {

    const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
    const sgTransport = require('nodemailer-sendgrid-transport');
    const options = {
      auth: {
        api_user: 'webinar-wc',
        api_key: 'Webinarwc20@',
      }
    }
    const client = nodemailer.createTransport(sgTransport(options));
  
    const email = {
      from: 'shubham.jadhav@whitecode.co.in',
      to: 'shubhamjadhavsrj120@gmail.com',
      subject: 'Hello',
      text: message,
      html: '<b>Hello world</b>'    
    };
    client.sendMail(email, function(err, info) {
      return err? err.message : 'Message sent: ' + info.response;
    });
  }
  
  module.exports = (on, config) => {
    on('task', {
      sendMail (message) {
        return sendAnEmail(message);
      }
    })
  }

This is my commands.js file
```